# Why stored duplicate rows to table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, duplicates, laravel-6

I have custom query for adding parsed remote posts to table:

```
foreach ($parsedPosts as $post) {
    $hasRemotePostAlready = Post::where('remote_post_id', $post->id)->first();
    if(null === $hasRemotePostAlready) {
        $data = [
            'title' => $post->title,
            'description' => $post->description,
            'remote_post_id' => $post->id
        ];
        Post::create($data);
    }
}
```

Variable `$parsedPosts` has more then 3500 posts and when I run my script to add posts then any remote posts duplicated. Why they posts duplicated and why not work my condition:

```
$hasRemotePostAlready = Post::where('remote_post_id', $post->id)->first();
```

How I can fix duplicating rows problem in my case?

Comment: your code is working in my case. though you can try with `if(!$hasRemotePostAlready)` and check what happens.

Comment: just remove one equalto(=)  from condition if(null == $hasRemotePostAlready)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `firstOrCreate` or `updateOrCreate` methods for this case, take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#other-creation-methods)

In your case try this:

```
$hasRemotePostAlready = Post::firstOrCreate(
  [
      'remote_post_id' => $post->id // columns to check if record exists
  ],

  [
      'title' => $post->title,
      'description' => $post->description
  ]
);
```

Comment: Your answer is correct.

 But note that this is not exactly equals to the scenario in the question. You see, the code says, store if there is not already found, but don't do anything at all if found. Actually `updateOrCreate` will create if not found, and will __update if found__. I think you can understand my point :) .... So your answer may correct or may not depends..

Comment: @TharakaDilshan he can use firstOrCreate then, I just gave an example of the usage.